# How tiff image IFDs are stored in memory

Tags: c, unix, data-structures, tiff, libtiff

I am using 
tiff 4.0.8 (libtiff)
Ubuntu 14.04
Tiff 6.0 specifications

When a tiff image is opened on the computer, how IFDs(Image File Directory) are stored in memory.

I guess IFDs are stored randomly in memory with data structures linking.

Comment: I have an image with 1IFD and which has 17 tag entries.

Comment: How IFDs are stored in memory, is an implementation detail in the library. If want to know how it's done in libtiff for educational purposes, I suggest looking at the libtiff source code. Other libraries might do it differently, and it doesn't really matter, as long as the decoder has enough information to decode the image.

Comment: Thanks, @haraldK I need to understand it as we want to add one more tag/IFD to Tiff using libtiff as part of my project.

Comment: It seems to me you should be looking at the libtiff API documentation, rather than worry about how the IFDs are stored in memory. I'm sure you'll find a way to add a tag to an IFD there.

Comment: It seems there is no proper website/documents for libtiff, can you please provide me the link to get documentation

Comment: @haraldK 
Can you please give me the webiste links for libtiff API documentation if you have

Comment: Asking for documentation is off-topic for SO, and it’s very easy to find. But anyway.. Second google hit for libtiff is the current official site, as far as I can see: http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/

Comment: Yeah, I have seen simplesystems link previously but there is no documentation for "how it is working".
Anyway thank you for your response @haraldK